# Select with Multiple Counts on Left Join on Same Table

Tags: mysql

I'm not certain that this can be done, I have a table of users with a related table of user activity joined on a foreign key. Activity has different types, e.g. comment, like etc. I need to get users filtered by the number of each different type of activity.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT
      users.*, 
      COUNT(t1.id) AS comments, 
      COUNT(t2.id) AS likes
FROM users
     LEFT JOIN activity AS t1 ON users.id = t1.user_id
     LEFT JOIN activity AS t2 ON users.id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.activity_type_id = 1 AND t2.activity_type_id = 2
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING comments >= 5 AND likes >= 5
```

This seems to be close but it's returning a user with a count of 5 both likes and comments, when in reality the user has 5 likes and 1 comment.

To be clear I want this query to return users who have 5 or more likes and *also users who have* 5 or more comments.

**UPDATE:**

I've created an SQL Fiddle. In this case I have 3 users:

- User 1: 6 comments, 8 likes
- User 2: 3 comments, 2 likes
- User 3: 5 comments, 2 likes

I want the query to return only user 1 and 3, with their respective totals of likes and comments.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcc63/4

Comment: Assuming my edit (italicised above) is correct, would 'or' not satisfy that requirement? Also you're outer joining tables from which you select no columns, so that might be a part of the problem. Consider providing an sqlfiddle and desired result.

Comment: I need this to be able to work with AND as well as OR conditions. My main problem right now is that the user's activity counts are not correct. Each type is coming back with the same count.

Comment: Remove GROUP BY and HAVING, and look at the records you get in your result data set … that should provide some insight as to why this can not work this way.

Comment: By removing GROUP BY and HAVING I get one record returned(not in the original result set) with a likes count of 420 and comments count of 420.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional summing to do the count and due to the way MySQL treats boolean expressions an expression like `sum(case when et.name = 'comment' then 1 else 0 end)` (the "normal" SQL syntax) can be reduced to `sum(case when et.name = 'comment')`.

```
SELECT
  u.id, 
  sum(et.name = 'comment') AS comments, 
  sum(et.name = 'like') AS likes
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN engagements AS  e ON u.id = e.user_id
JOIN engagement_types AS et ON e.engagement_type_id = et.id
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING sum(et.name = 'comment') >= 5 
    OR sum(et.name = 'like') >= 5
```

Result:

```
| ID | COMMENTS | LIKES |
|----|----------|-------|
|  1 |        6 |     8 |
|  3 |        5 |     2 |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc4c3f/8)